# Why WiFi connection drops while on a call in Android

Tags: android, android-wifi

I have a program which requires WiFi connections to be kept alive all the time. My problem is when the user make a phone call, after few seconds call connected Screen goes off and then WiFi connection drops.

I tried holding a `WIFI_MODE_FULL` on WiFi and `FULL_WAKE_LOCK` on `PowerManager` and by setting the `SCREEN_TIMEOUT` to -1 none of these helped. Still WiFi connection get disconnected. I am having this issue on LG-P990 Android 2.2.2

Does anybody know how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to keep the wifi connection alive by changing settings in Settings => Advanced => Keep Wifi- on during sleep